# Adding comment to query in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have an audit trigger on several tables in a PostgreSQL 9.2 db.  For reference, it is based on this [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) page.  It logs the client_query that was run as part of it.  When I'm manually running queries against production, I always add a comment at the top of the query with my initials and why I'm doing it and what I want to accomplish.  For example:

```
--DS: Per email from xxxx, moving account from customer yyyy to zzzz
update account set cust_id = zzzz where cust_id = yyyy;
```

It works great when using pgAdminIII.  However, if I'm using PSQL, I can't figure out how to get it to work.  If I start a query with `--` it just ignores it when hitting enter for the next line.  It's funny, it doesn't even add it to history (not there when you "up arrow".

I guess I can put it at the bottom, but that's not been my norm.  Any suggestions on how to force this?

note: it's minor, but annoying.  I'd love to know a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the /* */ style comments

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS